# How does the "self" work in this python code

Tags: python, self

Have two simple python codes, both are working. But no sure what is the "self" in there that makes the difference. When to use and when not to use "self"?

```
class car:
 colour="red"
 def method1():
   print("method1")
myCar=car
myCar.method1()

class car:
 colour="red"
 def method1(self):
   print("method1")
myCar=car()
myCar.method1()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first snippet, `myCar` refers to the class `car`, and `method1` appears to be being used as a static method of that class.

In the second snippet, `myCar` refers to an *instance* of the class `car`, and `method1` is an instance method -- the typical usage. Instance methods receive as a first argument the instance calling the method.

Conceptually, the difference is that in the second snippet you're referring to *a car* and in the first snippet you're referring to *the concept of cars in general*.

Comment: Thanks Adam ... understand now. Appreciate your reply.